# How do you create virtual hosts (that also use SSL) on localhost with MAMP and Apache?

Tags: php, apache, virtualhost

Suppose you have a local project at `/Users/yourname/Sites/example` and want to be able to use both `http://example.local` and `https://example.local` to reach it on your Mac, using MAMP (I'm using MAMP version 6.6).

Read the answer for the steps to take.

Answer (score 2):

### 1) Add your custom domain to the hosts file

Open the Finder and choose the `Go to folder` command from the `Go` menu. Enter `/private/etc/hosts` as the path; this will open a Finder window where you will find the `hosts` file.

Open the `hosts` file and map your custom domain to 127.0.0.1 (localhost):

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 example.local
```

Now, when you visit `http://example.local`, the browser will redirect you to localhost and show your list of local sites (which is not what we want yet, but hey, this is just the first step).

### 2) Configure MAMP to use Apache's and MySql's default ports

Open MAMP, click on `Preferences`, then go the `Ports` tab. By default, MAMP uses port 8888 for Apache and 8889 for MySQL, but it gives you the option to use Apache's default port (80) as well as MySQL's default port (3306): click the `80 & 3306` button to use these ports rather than 8888 and 8889.

### 3) Enable virtual hosts in Apache

Go to and open the `/Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/httpd.conf` file. Look for this line:

```
# Include /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

Uncomment the line by removing the asterisk at the beginning: **uncommenting the line enables virtual hosts**. (If the line is already uncommented, you're good to go for this step).

### 4) Configure Apache to listen to port 80

While you have `/Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/httpd.conf` open, also look for this line:

```
Listen 8888
```

and change it to

```
Listen 80
Listen 443
```

In the previous step, you told MAMP to use port 80 for Apache, so the first line tells Apache to listen to port 80 rather than port 8888; the second line tells Apache to also listen to requests incoming on port 443: this is the port typically used by SSL connections, so it is an essential step to be able to reach your local site at `https://` besides `http://`.

### 5) Create a SSL certificate for your local site

You need a SSL certificate to be able to reach your site at `https://example.local` as well. This can be easily done using the **[mkcert](https://github.com/FiloSottile/mkcert)** tool. You can read the instructions on Github, but basically it's about installing the tool, then running:

```
$ mkcert example.local
```

This generates two files: a certificate (`example.local.pem`) and a certificate key (`example.local-key.pem`).

Move these two files somewhere within your project. For example, you could create a hidden folder at the root of your project called `.crt` and put them in there.

### 6) Create a virtual host for your local site

Finally, it's time to actually create a virtual host for your local site. Go to and open the `/Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` file and include the following:

```
// These first two lines tell Apache to check for virtual hosts 
// whenever a request comes in on port 80 (http://) or 443 (https://)

NameVirtualHost *:80
NameVirtualHost *:443

// This first directive tells Apache to serve the files at "/Users/yourname/Sites/example"
// whenever "http://example.local" is visited 

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.local
    DocumentRoot "/Users/yourname/Sites/example"
</VirtualHost>

// This second directive tells Apache to serve the files at "/Users/yourname/Sites/example"
// whenever "https://example.local" is visited, and provides paths to the certificates
// we previously created 

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName example.local
    DocumentRoot "/Users/yourname/Sites/example"
    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile "/Users/yourname/Sites/example/.crt/example.local.pem"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "/Users/yourname/Sites/example/.crt/example.local-key.pem"
</VirtualHost>
```

**That's it! Now you can view your site at both `http://example.local` and `https://example.local`**

(Remember to adapt the paths to wherever your project and certificates are located though).

### 7) Need virtual hosts for multiple local sites?

Want to add virtual hosts for more local sites you have, eg. for a site you want to reach at `http://test.local`?

Go to `/private/etc/hosts` and add `127.0.0.1 test.local`

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 example.local
127.0.0.1 test.local
```

Generate SSL certificates with `mkcert test.local` (like we did earlier on step 4).

Finally, update the virtual hosts file as follows:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
NameVirtualHost *:443

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.local
    DocumentRoot "/Users/yourname/Sites/example"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName example.local
    DocumentRoot "/Users/yourname/Sites/example"
    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile "/Users/yourname/Sites/example/.crt/example.local.pem"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "/Users/yourname/Sites/example/.crt/example.local-key.pem"
</VirtualHost>

// Basically, copy and paste the virtual hosts for the example project 
// and update the domain and paths accordingly

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName test.local
    DocumentRoot "/Users/yourname/Sites/test"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName test.local
    DocumentRoot "/Users/yourname/Sites/test"
    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile "/Users/yourname/Sites/test/.crt/test.local.pem"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "/Users/yourname/Sites/test/.crt/test.local-key.pem"
</VirtualHost>
```

### 8) Bonus: add extra configuration to your virtual hosts

The VirtualHost directive can accept a number of extra instructions that tell Apache what to do when a certain request is received.

For instance, suppose our example project is a Node application that can be reached at `http://localhost:3000`, but we want to use `http://example.local` to access it. We would have to tell Apache to forward any request made to `http://example.local` to `http://localhost:3000`.

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
NameVirtualHost *:443

// This line loads a module that enables proxying (it's turned off by default)

LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so 

// The ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse lines tell Apache 
// to forward the request to http:// and https://localhost:3000

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.local
    DocumentRoot "/Users/yourname/Sites/example"
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/ 
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3000/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName example.local
    DocumentRoot "/Users/yourname/Sites/example"
    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile "/Users/yourname/Sites/example/.crt/example.local.pem"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "/Users/yourname/Sites/example/.crt/example.local-key.pem"
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/ 
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3000/
</VirtualHost>
```